geodetic: a second order derivative
I would like to understand in the snippets below how was derived $(7.19b)$ from $(7.19a)$
and the formulas above it. Namely the second order derivative in $(7.19b)$.
The snipets were taken from an interesting book by Nakahara:Geometry,Topology and Physics.



The drivative of a a moving point $t\to x\mu(t)$ for all coordinates on curve is a tangent vector

The derivative of a a moving point $t\to x^\mu(t)$ for all coordinates on a curve is a tangent vector $$v(t)= \frac{d}{dt} x^\mu(t)\ e_\mu(x(t))$$ The second derivative is the acceleration, that is zero for a geodesic. By the product and chain formula one has $$\frac{d}{dt} v(t)^\mu e_\mu(x(t)) = \left(\frac{d}{dt}  v^\mu(t)\right) \ e_\mu(x(t))  + v^\mu(x(t))\  \frac{d}{dt} e_{\mu}(x(t))$$
The term with the derivative of the basis is by  chain rule and a partial derivative $\nabla_k$ of the vector field wrt to th k-th coordinate
$$v^\mu(t)\ \frac{d}{dt} \ e_\mu (x^1(t),\dots x^n(t)) \ = \ v^\mu(t) \  \nabla_k e_\mu(x^1(t),\dots  x^n(t) )) \ \frac{d}{dt} x^k(t) \ = v^\mu(t) \ v^k(t) \  \Gamma^s_{\mu k}(x(t)) \  e_s(x(t))$$.
The Levi-Civita connection with Christoffel coefficients for geodesics on a Riemannian menifold with metric G are the result of Euler-Legendre equations of free motion as the condition to extremize the kinetic energy on the tangent space
$$\delta\int G(v(t),v(t))dt \ = \ 0$$
if the 'time' is the arc length of the curve as result of the integral of the norm of the velocity along the curve.

Nice that you have replied. But I cannot read off $(7.19b)$ from your answer  :-( Could you be more close to my snippets, why there are such and such items in $(7.19b)$ ?

Are you sure about the indices? $x$ somehow ends with $\nu$ instead with $n$ and the Einstein's summation convention is not apparent (because there are no repeated indices lower and upper one). Also I do not fully understand that calculation, perhaps you could improve your answer and include this  observation in more detail into it ?

Thanks for the hint, done, hopefully balanced now.

Thank you for your answer. However, how have you derived in the -8th line the = there ? Namely the $\nabla_k$ ?

The linear approximation $d e_\mu (x(t)) =\nabla_k  e_\mu (x(t)) dx^k$ involves a translation map $\Lambda $ between different tangent vector spaces: $e_{(x+dx})  = dx\  e_x \  \Lambda^x_{{x+dx}} $. The definitions of the covariant $\nabla$ are selected in order to maintain two facts: save the integral theorems (Gauss, Stokes, ) and the differential calculus with $\partial \to \nabla$.
